# select the maximum item per year in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the max count/per year.

I have a table with this kind of data:

```
Years   shipvia count
---------------------
2002    1       38
2002    2       56
2002    3       58
2003    1       134
2003    2       152
2003    3       122
2004    1       78
2004    2       117
2004    3       75
```

Expected output:

```
Years   shipvia count
---------------------
2002    3       58
2003    2       152
2004    2       117
```

I have tried the query below, but it gives me wrong data:

```
SELECT  Years,
        ShipVia,
        max(count)
FROM table
GROUP BY Years, ShipVia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Years] ORDER BY [Count] DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT [Years], shipvia, [count]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: What is CTE doing in this scenario, @Lamak? Sorry to jump in, but could you explain (if it's brief - if not don't worry about it)

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA The CTE is not doing very much, really, it could be a derived table just the same. The important part is the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`. That function ranks according to the `ORDER BY` defined in it, and starts again for every different value of `[years]` (defined in the `PARTITION BY`). So in this case, it will return 1 for the maximum value of `[count]` for a year, 2 for the second and so on for every value of that `[year]` and it will do that for every `[year]`